# code for using O365 groups in a .net core app

Tags: .net-core, office365

I am working on a .net core app and have to integrate O365 security groups for roles assignment, does someone have sample code to share, will be very helpful.

I have already used Azure AD app registration concept for O365 authentication and its working perfectly. .Net core app is hosted on IIS, when accessed by typing in url in browser, it redirects users to login.microsoftonline.com, once authenticated, users then see dashboard part of .net core app.

Not so sure about how O365 groups can be used in .net core app for permissions management, so looking for some sample snippet, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Office365 security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/email/create-edit-or-delete-a-security-group?view=o365-worldwide) can be used for permissions management in your app, by [verifying if a user is a member of a security group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/groups-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#security-groups-and-mail-enabled-security-groups). You can achieve that by using [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?toc=./toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0) as [MohitVerma suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802335/2869093).

First, define groups to roles mapping in your app (configuration file seems to be a good place for that). Each group has a unique id, which you can get using e.g. [Office365 or Microsoft Graph](https://pgbhoyar.com/2017/02/04/how-to-find-id-of-office-365-group/) and map to a custom role in your `config.json` file:

```
{
    "AppRoles": [
        "Admin": "d17a5f86-57f4-48f8-87a0-79761dc8e706",
        "Manager": "9a6a616e-5637-4306-b1fe-bceeaa750873"
    ]
}
```

Then, after successful login to the app, [call the Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0) to get all groups the user belongs to. You will get a list of groups, each containing `id` property:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.directoryRole",
            "id": "43a63cc2-582b-4d81-a79d-1591f91d5558",
            "displayName": "Company Administrator",
            "roleTemplateId": "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10"
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
            "id": "d17a5f86-57f4-48f8-87a0-79761dc8e706",
            "createdDateTime": "2017-07-31T17:36:25Z",
            "displayName": "Admins group",
            "securityEnabled": true
        }
    ]
}
```

You can use [MS Graph SDK for .NET](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) to make a request and to create a group objects form the response:

```
var userGroups = await graphServiceClient.Me.Groups.Request().GetAsync();
```

Finally, verify the id of each group with your custom roles, e.g.:

```
public string GetRole(IEnumerable<Group> userGroups, IConfiguration config) 
{
    foreach (var group in userGroups) 
    {
        switch (group.id) 
        {
            case config.GetSection("AppRoles:0"):
                return "Admin";
            case config.GetSection("AppRoles:1"):
                return "Manager";
            default:
                return "Unknown";
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to [grant permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-overview) for your app to access Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 3):

You can query graph api either as your app or impersonate the user, to read which groups the user is in and then use those Id to filter views or what ever you need to do.

you can use the "List memberOf"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0

Hope it helps.